# jquery get() does not give errors when an invalid url is provided

Tags: jquery

i noticed that when i provide an invalid URL to `get()` i get no errors

```
$.get(nextHref, function(data, status, xhr) {
  alert(status);
  if (status == "error") {
    alert("an error has occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
```

`alert(status);` nv even runs when i provide an invalid URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) callback is a **success** function, so this will never run on error, you can either use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the full version, or rig up a global error event handler, whichever is more appropriate.

If you want to use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), use the `error` callback, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: nextHref,
  success: function(data) {
    //do something with good data, what comes after your if statement currently
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert("an error has occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

Or use the global event handler [`$().ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) like this:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr) {
    alert("an error has occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);   
});
```

Or, use [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to add an `error` handler for all requests, like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert("an error has occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) page:

> If a request with jQuery.get() returns an error code, it will fail silently unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError() method.

Read about the ajaxError [here](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/).

Basically what you need to do is to attach `ajaxError` to some item, and handle the error from there:

**We can attach our event handler to any element:**

```
$('.log').ajaxError(function() {
  $(this).text('Triggered ajaxError handler.');
});
```

**Now, we can make an Ajax request using any jQuery method:**

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
  $('.result').load('ajax/missing.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to catch the error use this :

```
$.ajax({
   url : url,
   success : function(result) {
      //doSomething
   },
   error : function(request, status, error) {
       if(status == 'parsererror' || status == 'error') {
         //doSomething
       }
   }
});
```